# How to set view outlet for a UITableViewController?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I created an empty xib, I dragged a UITableViewController, set Custom class to my class that extends from UITableViewController at both the UITableViewController and File's Owner.

When I run, it says:

> 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with . Clear this association before associating this view with .'

At connections inspector I see that the UITableViewController element has:

- tableView - Table View
- view - Table View (greyed)
- dataSource - Table View
- delegate - Table View

First Responder has nothing.

File's Owner has:

- tableView is not attached to anything
- view - Table View

If I remove the view connection at File's Owner, it claims that the view outlet is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the correct answer is DON'T drag UITableViewController to the interface builder. Have 2 IBOutlets connected, one for the view, one for the table. DO drag a UITableView instead.

Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to imagine what happens based on the information provided. However:
The error message says that you have a `UIView`, and you try at runtime to connect this `UIView` to **two** `UIViewControllers`, which is not possible.
If you just subclass a `UITableViewController`, without adding properties or implementing methods, then setup a `UITableViewController` in an empty storyboard, and set the class of this `UITableViewController` to your subclass, you have **only a single** `UITableViewController`, and you will not get this error.
So somewhere in your project you must instantiate **a second** `UITableViewController` programmatically, and set its `UIView` property (which is a `UITableView`) to the `UIView` **of the other** `UITableViewController`.
You should ensure that you have **only a single** `UITableViewController`, namely your custom subclass.

Comment: Thanks Reinhard. I'm not using storyboard. I found a solution by not using UITableViewController at all. So my class now extends from UIViewController and in the xib I have a view that contains a tableview. In my M file I have 2 IBOutlets connected to them.